# Session callback expects true/false return value

Tags: php

My php script, sometimes, give me the following error:

```
    Warning: session_start(): Session callback expects true/false return 
value in C:\xampp\htdocs\verifica.php on line 10
```

verifica.php line 10:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start(); //this is line 10
}
```

what is wrong? why I have this error? this only shows when it wants, not always...

Comment: var_dump(session_status());

Comment: int(1) after if and int(2) before if

Comment: before id means it should be (1==1) right? should u to use ===

Comment: oh, sorry, var_dump shows me int(1) before the `if` and int(2) after `if`

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem when code used [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) with object and I've fixed the issue by returning boolean from _destroy method, I think that all handlers need to return true/false.

Comment: They do.  See http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php.

Comment: Well, true. No pun intended. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to do this :

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    session_start(); 
}
```

The different values :

```
PHP_SESSION_DISABLED = 0
PHP_SESSION_NONE = 1
PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE = 2
```

Do you still have the same error ?

Comment: thank you for your answer! I'll try this! this error is strange, appears 1 in 10 times usually...